# SuiteScript - Unexpected Error Record.Save()

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, user-event

For some reason, I am receiving an error when `caseRecord.save()` is executed. I am unaware if I have missed something but I have looked over this multiple times and can't seem to figure out why I am unable to save the newly created record.

Basically, I am creating a support case whenever an RMA is created and approved. Can someone take a look at the code to see if I missed anything?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/format", "N/log", "N/record", "N/search"], /**
 * @param{format} format
 * @param{log} log
 * @param{record} record
 * @param{search} search
 */ (format, log, record, search) => {
  /**
   * Defines the function definition that is executed before record is loaded.
   * @param {Object} context
   * @param {Record} context.newRecord - New record
   * @param {string} context.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
   * @param {Form} context.form - Current form
   * @param {ServletRequest} context.request - HTTP request information sent from the browser for a client action only.
   * @since 2015.2
   */
  const beforeLoad = (context) => {};

  /**
   * Defines the function definition that is executed before record is submitted.
   * @param {Object} context
   * @param {Record} context.newRecord - New record
   * @param {Record} context.oldRecord - Old record
   * @param {string} context.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
   * @since 2015.2
   */
  const beforeSubmit = (context) => {
    const currentRecord = context.newRecord;
    const status = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "orderstatus" });
    const customForm = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "customform" });
    const customer = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "entity" });
    const location = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "location" });
    const salesOrderId = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "custbody_originalsalesorder" });
    const rmaId = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "id" });
    const salesRepId = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "custbody_insidesalesrep" });
    const existingCase = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "custbody_caseinternalid" });

    //Static Values
    const caseType = 9; //RMA
    const assignedTo = 6732844; 
    var existingPartNumber = null;

    log.debug({ title: "Context Type", details: context.type });
    log.debug({ title: "Current Record", currentRecord });
    log.debug({ title: "RMA ID", details: rmaId });

    if ((customForm != 266 || customForm != 269) && context.type == "approve") {
      if (existingCase == null || existingCase == undefined || existingCase == "") {
        log.debug({ title: "Action", details: "****START****" });
        const getLineCount = currentRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: "item" });
        if (getLineCount > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < getLineCount; i++) {
            var invType = currentRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: "item", fieldId: "itemtype", line: i });
            //First Loop to get the location & class from the inventory item.
            if (invType == "InvtPart" || invType == "Assembly") {
              existingPartNumber = currentRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: "item", fieldId: "item", line: i });
              log.debug({
                title: "Invntory Item",
                details: "Located inventory item on line number " + (i + 1) + ". Grabbing values.",
              });
              break;
            }
          }

          log.debug({ title: "Action", details: "Starting Case Creation" });

          var caseRecord = record.create({
            type: record.Type.SUPPORT_CASE,
            isDynamic: true,
          });

          log.debug({ title: "Action", details: "Case Creation" });

          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "customform", value: 49 });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "category", value: caseType });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "assigned", value: assignedTo });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custevent_caselocation", value: location });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "company", value: customer });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "item", value: existingPartNumber });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custevent_existingpartlink", value: existingPartNumber });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custevent_salesorder", value: salesOrderId });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custevent_rmarecord", value: rmaId });
          caseRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custevent_salesrep", value: salesRepId });

          log.debug({ title: "Action", details: "Case values have been set" });

          var caseId = caseRecord.save({
            enableSourcing: true,
            ignoreMandatoryFields: true,
          });

          log.debug({ title: "Case ID", details: caseId });

          currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: "custbody_caseinternalid", value: caseId });

          log.debug({ title: "Action", details: "****END****" });
        }
      } else {
        log.debug({ title: "Existing Case", details: "This record already hase a case assigned." });
      }
    } else if (status == "A") {
      log.debug({ title: "Record Status", details: "Record needs to be approved to create case" });
    } else {
      log.debug({ title: "Custom Form", details: `The form that was used is restricted. Form: ${customForm}` });
    }
  };

  /**
   * Defines the function definition that is executed after record is submitted.
   * @param {Object} context
   * @param {Record} context.newRecord - New record
   * @param {Record} context.oldRecord - Old record
   * @param {string} context.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
   * @since 2015.2
   */
  const afterSubmit = (context) => {};

  return { beforeLoad, beforeSubmit, afterSubmit };
});
```

Error

```
{
"type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
"name": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
"message": "An unexpected SuiteScript error has occurred",
"stack": [
"Error\n at RecordInvoker.save (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/serverRecordService.js:371:13)\n at NetSuiteObject.thenableFunction() (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/proxy.js:74:24)\n at Object.beforeSubmit (/SuiteScripts/Production Files/2.0 Converted Scripts/epec_ue_rma_create_case.js:102:35)"
],
"cause": {
"type": "internal error",
"code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
"details": "An unexpected SuiteScript error has occurred",
"userEvent": null,
"stackTrace": [
"Error\n at RecordInvoker.save (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/serverRecordService.js:371:13)\n at NetSuiteObject.thenableFunction() (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/proxy.js:74:24)\n at Object.beforeSubmit (/SuiteScripts/Production Files/2.0 Converted Scripts/epec_ue_rma_create_case.js:102:35)"
],
"notifyOff": false
},
"id": "",
"notifyOff": false,
"userFacing": true
}
```

Comment: Are there any user event scripts or workflows on the case record that could be throwing the error instead?

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown from within the code? So I guess my question would be what is the last log that prints? Or the first one that dose not print.

I would also make sure the script is causing it. Remove the scripts deployment. Try doing the same thing in the UI.